# Cannot connect to sharepoint site

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to connect to Sharepoint to read an Excel file but it crashes at line: Execute Query. Error is: Unable to connect to Sharepoint site.

I tried giving URL in all sorts of ways but it is not working.

```
        string userName = "My Email";
        string password = "12345";
        var siteurl = "https://xyz.sharepoint.com//sites//MySystems";
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteurl))
        {
            var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
            clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web, a => a.ServerRelativeUrl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual, full exception text? You can easily get this with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup during debugging. The full text shows any inner exceptions and the stack trace that shows which calls led to the exception. `Unable to connect to Sharepoint site.` could mean anything - bad credentials, no authorization for *that* site, something else. Can you log into that site with those credentials in the first place? Perhaps the account doesn't work with *that* site collectin

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, if I paste the URL, it automatically logs me in. ADFS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actual exception is just this one: "Cannot contact site at the specified URL ...." . After this the same URL. No other details.

Comment: Again you posted just part of the message, not the exception. It's not even the full message. The missing part is telling you why you can't connect. Perhaps there's no such site collection? There's no `MySystems`?  Post the string returned by `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: In any case, ADFS means that *federation* is used. You aren't logging in with a SharePoint online account, you're logging in with *your* Windows Domain account. SharePoint Online trusts your domain and asks it whether the authentication token sent by the browser is a valid account in that domain.

Comment: Try using `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` instead of `SharePointOnlineCredentials` to log in with your account or `new NetworkCredentials("domain","user","password")` to specify a different domain account

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When using Network Credentials, it is giving bad request 400 error. I passed securePassword instead of plain text Password.